# Resources in Application Page

Tags: application-pages, resource-files

I've created an application page with a dropdown that's using resources, like this:

```
<SharePoint:DVDropDownList ID="ContentTypesDropDown" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:Yucatan.Global.UI,Devider; %>" Value="" />
</SharePoint:DVDropDownList>
```

This resource is an AppGlobalResource. I've double checked that the resource file is in the App_GlobalResources.

Somehow the resource isn't working. It just shows as an empty string. I've also tried with a resource file in the resources directory of sharepoint, but then I get an exception. Does anyone know why the resource text isn't showing?

Comment: Hi, Marlou! Are you sure about Class and ResourceID? 
Also, where are some resource bug with powershell deployment, but if you don't using powershell to deploy, you won't be take it.
Did you miss runat attribute of asp:ListItem?

Comment: Hi IAfanasov! I'm sure about class and resourceid, double checked that :) I've deployed directly from vs2010. I don't think the asp:ListItem needs a runat attribute, but i'm going to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the extra semicolon after resource key name "Devider" is causing the problem. It is not required.